# Can I write a single stored procedure for multiple select queries?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have three different select queries that produce three different outputs. Can I encapsulate all that in a single stored procedure? But then how can I return the three different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the results of the queries simple (e.g. one string or number or date/time, not multi-record sets of rows)?

If the results for each are simple (one or handful of records) perhaps you can build an array and load the records into the array, or maybe even JSON, and return that.

If the results are larger result sets, I'd simply store the results in temporary tables, and have the calling routine query the result set temporary tables.

Most of the stored procedure work I've done using javascript SPs and I've simply only returned an array of status/debug type of info, and haven't returned result sets for processing, it would be a lot easier and cleaner to simply create the temp tables and use those in your process after the CALL command.

I hope this helps...Rich

EDIT AS FOLLOWS - Adding Example code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_return_array(p1 varchar)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE javascript
EXECUTE AS caller
AS 
$$
try {
   var return_array = [];
   var counter = 0;

   var p1_str = "p1: " + P1
   return_array.push(p1_str)

   const procName = Object.keys(this)[0];
   var pName_str = "procName: " + procName;
   return_array.push(pName_str)

   var sqlquery = "SELECT current_date()::varchar as str;";
   var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sqlquery} );
   var rs = stmt.execute();

   // Loop through the results, processing one row at a time... 
   while (rs.next())  {
       var currentDate_str = rs.getColumnValue(1);
       return_array.push("current_date: " + currentDate_str);
       }

   var sqlquery2 = "SELECT current_user()::varchar as str UNION ALL SELECT current_role()::varchar;";
   var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sqlquery2} );
   var rs2 = stmt2.execute();

   // Loop through the results, processing one row at a time... 
   while (rs2.next())  {
       counter = counter + 1;
       var str = rs2.getColumnValue(1);
       return_array.push(counter + ": " + str);
       }

   return_array.push("end process - counter: " + counter);

   return return_array;
   }

catch (err) {
   return_array.push("error found");
   return_array.push("err.code: " + err.code);
   return_array.push("err.state: " + err.state);
   return_array.push("err.message: " + err.message);
   return_array.push("err.stacktracetxt: " + err.stacktracetxt);
   return return_array;
}

$$;

CALL sp_return_array('Hello World');

[
  "p1: Hello World",
  "procName: SP_RETURN_ARRAY",
  "current_date: 2020-06-05",
  "1: RICH",
  "2: RICH_ROLE",
  "end process - counter: 2"
]
```